# Magento admin login failed on cloud server

Tags: php, magento, web-hosting, magento-1.9, online-store

I have purchased a magento theme to build my fashion store. At first I purchased a Linux 10GB web hosting package and I finished my website successfully on that. But after that I realized the web server that I purchased is not stable. There were multiple server down times. So I decided to buy a unlimited Cloud Hosting package. After that I tried to install the same theme "quick-start package" on it. But after installing it it doesn't allow me to login to the admin panel. It says Invalid Username or Password. Please help me to fix this problem. Is there any service that I have to enable? cURLS and mod-rewrite are enabled.

I modified the password from database. But it didn't work.

Comment: If you modify any password directly from the database it wont work.. Magento follows a security hashing and this hash key would be defined in local.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help - this isn't my answer but I know its worked for people with the same issue.

Id put your password back as it was - hope you kept a backup!

If you are having trouble to get logged in with the correct username and password, here are some ideas. If you have used google chrome to install magento, use firefox to open magento and edit the app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php file within your magento directory and comment those below lines

```
    $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath()
        // 'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        // 'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        // 'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );
```

And use your credentials to log in. I hope this works for you!!!